# scroll en css grid

Tags: css, css-grid-layout

No logro un grid que contenga un scroll en uno de sus elementos y que a su vez los elementos se ajusten.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  height: 500px;
  background: tomato;
}

aside {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.A {
  height: auto; 
  display: grid; 
}

.B {
  display: grid; 
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.D {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.C {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #07f;
}

.E {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
<aside class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C">search</div>
    <div class="D">
      <div class="E">1</div>
      <div class="E">2</div>
      <div class="E">3</div>
      <div class="E">4</div>
      <div class="E">5</div>
      <div class="E">6</div>
      <div class="E">7</div>
      <div class="E">8</div>
      <div class="E">9</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="C">elemento que debe ajustarse al de arriba</div>
  </div>
</aside>

<aside class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C">search</div>
    <div class="D">
      <div class="E">1</div>
      <div class="E">2</div>
      <div class="E">3</div>
      <div class="E">4</div>
      <div class="E">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="C">elemento que debe ajustarse al de arriba</div>
  </div>
</aside>
</main>
```

en el primer caso no hay problema porque hay overflow, pero en cuando no hay suficientes elementos me los espacia por el grid.
He probado con `height: min-content;` y `grid-auto-row: min-content` parece que funciona pero en el primer caso el overflow deja de funcionar.

Comment: Tienes una clase B en el css, pero no el el html... para que es eso ?

Comment: @Excorpion He corregigo el código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he conseguido solucionarlo, simplemente hay que trabajar el alineamiento de los elementos en vez de el tamaño de estos.

Finalmente añadí a la clase `.A`  un `align-content: flex-start;` para que subiera todo arriba

Me ha sido muy útil este [grid cheatshet](https://grid.malven.co/)

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  height: 500px;
  background: tomato;
}

aside {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.A {
  height: auto; 
  display: grid;
  align-content: flex-start; /* este es el añadido*/
}

.B {
  display: grid; 
  /* aqui tambien funcionaria */
  /* align-content: flex-start; */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.D {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.C {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #07f;
}

.E {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
<aside class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C">search</div>
    <div class="D">
      <div class="E">1</div>
      <div class="E">2</div>
      <div class="E">3</div>
      <div class="E">4</div>
      <div class="E">5</div>
      <div class="E">6</div>
      <div class="E">7</div>
      <div class="E">8</div>
      <div class="E">9</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="C">elemento que debe ajustarse al de arriba</div>
  </div>
</aside>

<aside class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C">search</div>
    <div class="D">
      <div class="E">1</div>
      <div class="E">2</div>
      <div class="E">3</div>
      <div class="E">4</div>
      <div class="E">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="C">elemento que debe ajustarse al de arriba</div>
  </div>
</aside>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Jugué un buen poco con los valores entre las clases A y C.
Aún no comprendo de donde viene la clase B, por lo que ha sido eliminada.

Lo importante es saber definir height y max-height, ambas usandose diferente.

Ahora lo último, es saber si esto se aproxima a lo que estás buscando o no.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  background: tomato;
}

aside {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.A {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 470px;
}

.C {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.D {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.E {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>
    <div class="A">
      <div class="C">searchC</div>
      <div class="D">
        <div class="E">1</div>
        <div class="E">2</div>
        <div class="E">3</div>
        <div class="E">4</div>
        <div class="E">5</div>
        <div class="E">6</div>
        <div class="E">7</div>
        <div class="E">8</div>
        <div class="E">9</div>
        <div class="E">10</div>
        <div class="E">11</div>
        <div class="E">12</div>
        <div class="E">10</div>
        <div class="E">11</div>
        <div class="E">12</div>
        <div class="E">10</div>
        <div class="E">11</div>
        <div class="E">12</div>
      </div>
      <div class="C">elemento que debe ajustarse al de arriba</div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <aside>
    <div class="A">
      <div class="C">search</div>
      <div class="D">
        <div class="E">1</div>
        <div class="E">2</div>
        <div class="E">3</div>
        <div class="E">4</div>
        <div class="E">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="C">elemento que debe ajustarse al de arriba</div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: Me temo que no puedo darte por válido porque a la clase ´D´ le has puesto un tamaño prefijado, cuando este se desconoce, además de que ha dejado de ser un grid

Comment: Y que valor quieres darle a la clase D ?? Por que solo es cosa de editar ese valor y ya.

Comment: @Takyo no has aparecido para solucionar tu detalle.

Comment: D es de tamaño indefinido/dinámico. Finalmente he encontrado una solución que acabo de publicar. Gracias por el esfuerzo.

Comment: El tema es ese, nunca explicaste que D era un tamaño definido por algo más, es más, no has dicho que define el tamaño de D. De todos modos es eso, 1 valor lejos de la respuesta. De todos modos me agrada ver que hayas encontrado otra solución alterna ;)